# PHP and SQL Login Bind Vars

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

So I am writing a PHP login system, and so far its working, except for one thing, when I do this:

```
if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err) && empty($confirm_password_err) && empty($first_err) && empty($last_err)){

    // Prepare an insert statement
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, first, last) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_username, $param_password, $param_first, $param_last);

        // Set parameters
        $param_username = $username;
        $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash
        $param_first = $first;
        $param_last = $last;

        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            // Redirect to login page
            header("location: login.php");
        } else{
            echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
    }

    // Close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

But it comes up with this:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of elements in type
>   definition  string doesn't match number of bind variables

How can I fix this?

Comment: You need 4 s's in bind param

Comment: Next time consider to use Google search for the error message you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your number of `s` to 4:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_username, $param_password, $param_first, $param_last);
```

To

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $param_username, $param_password, $param_first, $param_last);
```

That's because the `types` number have to match the number of vars you are calling.

In your code, you are calling 4 variables, and I assume they are all strings, so all you have to use is `s` type, which stands for string.

You also have:

**i**   corresponding variable has type integer

**d**   corresponding variable has type double

**s**   corresponding variable has type string

**b**   corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets

Types are:

> types
>   A string that contains one or more characters which specify the types for the corresponding bind variables

[Look here for more information.](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)